# Trying to evaluate an improper integral using the methods of complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Im trying to evaluate $\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{ x^3 \sin x}{(x^2+1)^2} dx $. I write $f(z) = \frac{ z^3 \sin z}{(z-i)^2(z+i)^2}$. Let $\Gamma_R$ be the loop of the semicircle $\gamma_R$ (positive side) and $\mu_R = [-R,R]$ for $R$ large enough so that $i \in \Gamma_R$. let $g(z) = \frac{ z^3 e^{iz} }{(z^2+1)^2} $. I know $f(z) = Im (g(z))$. And after a computation, I have found

$$ Im ( \int_{\Gamma_R} g(z) ) = Im( 2 \pi i Res(f,i) ) = \frac{\pi }{e}$$

and I know

$$ \frac{  \pi}{e} = \lim_{R \to \infty} \left( \int_{-R}^R f(z) + \int_{\gamma_R} g(z) \right)$$

Here is where I have some dificulties, since I cant let $\int_{\gamma} g \to 0 $

I have this estimate:

$$ |g| = \frac{ |z|^3 |e^{iz}| }{|z^2 + 1|^2} \leq \frac{ |z^3| }{(|z|^2-1)^2 } = \frac{ R^2}{R^4 - 2R^2 +1} $$

And so

$$ \left| \int_{\gamma_R} g(z) \right| \leq \frac{ length( \gamma_R) R^3}{R^4-2R^2+1}= \frac{ \pi R^4}{R^4 - 2R^2 + 1}$$

And if we let $R \to \infty$, we dont get the above estimate go to zero as I wanted. Am I doing something wrong??

Comment: You need Jordan's lemma (or something similar) to show that the integral over $\gamma_R$ tends to $0$.

Comment: How do you know that $f(z) = Im (g(z))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.   You assumed that $|e^{i z}| = 1$; this is not true.  Rather, along the arc, when one parametrizes the arc by $z=R e^{i \theta}$:

$$|e^{i z}| = e^{-R \sin{\theta}}$$

Thus, we may write:

$$\left |i R \int_0^{\pi} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \frac{R^3 e^{i 3 \theta} e^{i R e^{i \theta}}}{(R^2 e^{i 2 \theta}+1)^2} \right | \le \frac{R^4}{(R^2-1)^2} \int_0^{\pi} d\theta \, e^{-R \sin{\theta}}$$

Now we use the fact that the sine is symmetric about $\theta=\pi/2$ and that $$\sin{\theta} \ge \frac{2}{\pi} \theta \quad \theta \in \left [ 0, \frac{\pi}{2} \right ]$$

so that we may conclude that

$$\left |i R \int_0^{\pi} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \frac{R^3 e^{i 3 \theta} e^{i R e^{i \theta}}}{(R^2 e^{i 2 \theta}+1)^2} \right | \le \frac{2 R^4}{(R^2-1)^2} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-2 R \theta/\pi} \le \frac{\pi R^3}{(R^2-1)^2}$$

which indeed vanishes as $R \to \infty$.

Comment: why do you have $i R $ outside the integral ?

Comment: $z = R e^{i \theta} \implies dz = i R e^{i \theta} d\theta$.